Whether to interprete Poisson model estimates as semielasticities or as marginal effects on expected counts
I am trying to better understand Poisson models whose coefficients are expressed in log-counts because counts are skewed. See example estimates on synthetic data below.
Some suggest interpreting log-counts as semielasticities eydx (which may seem tricky in linear models): The percent (or proportionate) change in expected y associated with a 1 unit change in x. I can verify this with the estimates below, observing that the eydx semielasticity is the same as the log-count coefficient. However, I would have thought that this operation/command transformed the model output. Since it does not, 1. what is the operation eydx working on, or put differently, are the outcome of margins estimates (whether eydx or otherwise) independent of the link function and distribution family of the GLM being implemented?
Besides eydx, there is also the dyex semielasticity which, as far as I would have thought, log transforms the independent variables. Given that Poisson already logs the expected count, I would think that dyex de facto resulted in the elasticity eyex; i.e. a one pct change in x is associated with a given pct change in counts. Clearly, this semielasticity and the elasticity return different numbers, pointing me back to question 1. (.5645448 dyex != 1.378144 eyex)
Granted that elasticities can be confusing (for non-economists), it is less clear to me why one would not instead calculate the seemingly simpler marginal effects dydx on predicted counts? But then again, I initially thought (as per question 1) that these estimates would still express the log of expected counts. So 2. if dydx express effects on changes in counts, are these effects themselves exponentiated? Or why doesn't this estimate equal that of the model expressed in incident-rate ratios, irr? (1.206968 dydx != 19.03731 irr)
3. doesn't the interpretation of semielasticities, let's say eydx, depend on the scale or range of the independent variable? With a range 0-1 a one-unit change is really a full-scale change, correct?
To be sure, I am aware that others recommend instead expressing the estimates as incident-rate ratios.
* https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/dae/poisson-regression/

use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/poisson_sim, clear
 
. qui su math
. qui replace math = (math-(r(min)))/(r(max)-r(min))*(1-0)+0

. poisson num_awards i.prog math, vce(robust)


Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =        200
                                                Wald chi2(3)      =      80.15
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -182.75225               Pseudo R2         =     0.2118

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
  num_awards |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        prog |
   academic  |   1.083859   .3218538     3.37   0.001     .4530373    1.714681
   vocation  |   .3698092   .4014221     0.92   0.357    -.4169637    1.156582
             |
        math |   2.946401   .4393767     6.71   0.000     2.085238    3.807563
       _cons |  -2.932095   .3752917    -7.81   0.000    -3.667654   -2.196537
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. margins, eydx(math) atmeans noatlegend

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =        200
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
ey/dx w.r.t. : math


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      ey/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        math |   2.946401   .4393767     6.71   0.000     2.085238    3.807563
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. margins, dydx(math) atmeans noatlegend

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =        200
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : math


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        math |   1.206968   .1737072     6.95   0.000     .8665079    1.547428
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. margins, dyex(math) atmeans noatlegend

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =        200
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/ex w.r.t. : math

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/ex   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        math |   .5645448   .0812495     6.95   0.000     .4052988    .7237908
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. margins, eyex(math) atmeans noatlegend

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =        200
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
ey/ex w.r.t. : math


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      ey/ex   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        math |   1.378144   .2055132     6.71   0.000     .9753453    1.780942
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


. poisson num_awards i.prog math, vce(robust) irr

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =        200
                                                Wald chi2(3)      =      80.15
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -182.75225               Pseudo R2         =     0.2118

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
  num_awards |        IRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        prog |
   academic  |   2.956065   .9514208     3.37   0.001     1.573083    5.554903
   vocation  |   1.447458   .5810418     0.92   0.357     .6590449    3.179049
             |
        math |   19.03731   8.364552     6.71   0.000     8.046508    45.04056
       _cons |   .0532853   .0199975    -7.81   0.000     .0255363    .1111875
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: _cons estimates baseline incidence rate.



This discussion is based on the Stata documentation here
Notation:
$$\log \left(E(score|prog, math)\right) = \log(E(Y|x_1, x_2, x_3)) =  \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 \label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
Predicted counts:
$$\hat{y} = e^{\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_1 + \hat{\beta_2} x_2 + \hat{\beta_3} x_3} \label{eq2}\tag{2}$$
where

$x_1=1$ if prog is academic, zero otherwise
$x_2=1$ if prog is vocation, zero otherwise
$x_3$ is the math score

Page 24 and 25, with some derivations.  Note that the atmeans option is selected so the estimate of the elasticities are performed at the mean of the variable (also for categorical variables).

Change in $y$ for a change in $x$ aka the marginal effect of $x$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx_3} = \beta_3 y \label{eq3}\tag{3}$$
$\textbf{dydx} = \hat{\beta_3} e^{\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} \bar{x_1} + \hat{\beta_2} \bar{x_2} + \hat{\beta_3} \bar{x_3}} \label{eq4}\tag{4}$

Proportional change in $y$ for a change in $x$ aka the semi-elasticity of $y$:

$$\frac{d (\log y)}{dx_3} = \beta_3 = \frac{dy}{dx_3} \frac{1}{y} \label{eq5}\tag{5}$$
$\textbf{eydx} = \hat{\beta_3} \label{eq6}\tag{6}$

Change in $y$ for a proportional change in $x$ aka the semi-elasticity of $x$:

let $u=\log x_3$
$$\frac{d y}{d (\log x_3)} = \frac{d}{du} e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 e^{u}} = $$
$$ (e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 e^{u}}) (\beta_3 e^{u}) = y \beta_3 x_3 = \frac{dy}{dx_3} x_3 \label{eq7}\tag{7}$$
$\textbf{dyex} = \hat{\beta_3} \bar{x_3} e^{\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} \bar{x_1} + \hat{\beta_2} \bar{x_2} + \hat{\beta_3} \bar{x_3}} \label{eq8}\tag{8}$

Proportional change in $y$ for a proportional change in $x$ aka the elasticities of $y$ and $x$:

$$\frac{d (\log y)}{d (\log x_3)} =\frac{d}{du} \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 e^{u} = \beta_3 e^{u} = \beta_3 x_3 = \frac{dy}{dx_3} \frac{x_3}{y} \label{eq9}\tag{9}$$
$\textbf{eyex} = \hat{\beta_3} \bar{x_3} \label{eq10}\tag{10}$
Questions:

What is the operation eydx working on?  See above.

Does dyex result in the elasticity eyex?  No.  The derivation shows the difference.

Why one would not instead calculate the predicted counts based on seemingly simpler marginal effects dydx?  The predicted counts are $\hat{y}$ which comes from the regression equation.  The coefficient estimates are based on the marginal effects.

Doesn't the interpretation of semi-elasticities, let's say eydx, depend on the scale or range of the independent variable? With a range 0-1 a one-unit change is really a full-scale change, correct?  Yes, eydx does depend on the scale of the independent variable.  In this case $\beta_3$ depends on the scale of $x_3$.  If $x_3$ had a 0 to 1 range, then a one unit change in $x_3$ times $\beta_3$ would give the full-range change in the $\log \hat{y}$, holding the other covariates constant.


Edit
Follow-up Questions:
a. Are the four margins estimates independent of the GLM family and link function?  No.  For example, in a logistic regression:
$$\log \left( \frac{E(Y)}{1-E(Y)} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1$$
$$\hat{y} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1}}{1+e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx_1} = \beta_1 \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1}}{(1+e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1})^2}$$
b + c. If dydx express effects on changes in counts, are these effects themselves exponentiated? Or why doesn't this estimate equal that of the model expressed in incident-rate ratios, irr? (.0287373 dydx != 1.072672 irr).
dydx does not need to be exponentiated.  It is a simple application of the derivative of the prediction equation.
The reason the IRR (incident-rate ratio) does not equal the dydx is that dydx is not a ratio of incident rates, it is a change in counts or incidence with respect to another variable.  See below for more on the IRRs.
d. Would we need to take exp of eydx semielasticities to get the original scale (the count)?
Imagine a $y_1$ which has a math score of $x_3+1$ and $y_2$ with a math score of $x_3$, all else equal.  Take the ratio.
$$IRR_{x_3} = \frac{y_1}{y_2} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 (x_3+1)}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3}} = e^{\beta_3} \label{eq11}\tag{11}$$
Therefore $e^{\beta_3} = e^{\textbf{eydx}}$ is the ratio of counts due to a unit change in math score.
When we look at the incidence rate ratio for $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can simplify since only one of them can be one.
$$IRR_{x_1} = \frac{y_1}{y_2} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_3 x_3}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_3 x_3}} = e^{\beta_1}$$
$$IRR_{x_2} = \frac{y_1}{y_2} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_3}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_3 x_3}} = e^{\beta_2}$$
The IRR for the base case has a note in the Stata output because it doesn't really fit the pattern.  $IRR(base) = e^{\beta_0}$

+1 thanks. Your answer made me reformulate the questions. Please see above or the following summary: a. are the four margins estimates independent of the GLM family and link function (this is the new question 1.)? b. I don't completely understand your response to 2. (former 3.), please note the revised formulation about the scale of dydx. c. why does the estimate of dydx not equal the model expressed in incident-rate ratios irr? d. would we need to take exp of eydx semielasticities to get the original scale (the count)?

See the answer for responses.

Gave it another try.  Thanks for pointing out the IRRs in the output.

That is a solid and lengthy answer! I do have a minor comment. The code uses the atmeans option, which makes Stata evaluate the marginal effect at the mean value of covariates: a MEM. Your answer describes averaging the marginal effect in the sample using each observation's own covariates: an AME. In nonlinear models, these are distinct, can sometimes differ, and correspond to different thought experiments.

@dimitriy Thanks for your comment on the atmeans option.  I used the documentation from the "Expressing derivatives as elasticities" section which says "As margins always does with response functions, calculations are made at the observational level and are then averaged."  Is there another part of the documentation I should reference?

The atmeans option is explained in the At section of Options near the start of the pdf.

That's strictly correct as written. When you use atmeans, it's as if Stata replaces $_i$ with $\bar x$ for everyone and then takes the average of the MEs. That's mathematically equivalent to evaluating the marginal effect at the mean. When you leave out the atmeans option, the first step is omitted, but there is still averaging.

@dimitriy, I was able to get the original data and verify the calculations worked as you said.  I changed the estimation formulas to match.

@dimitriy thanks for chipping in too. And indeed thanks to RCarnell for a lengthy answer to a messy question. I appreciate the possibility to iterate over this.

@RCarnell Regarding follow-up .d, I intended to ask: Given that eydx estimates are expressed in log-counts, what do we need to do to interpret the effect in counts? Can we, for instance, determine or approximate the range of the log-count scale to get an idea of the effect size? Having scaled math (now ranging 0-1), the synthetic data suggests a log-count or an eydx of ~3. So a full-scale change in x is associated with a ~300% increase in counts. To understand what that is, would we need to consider that the count ranges 0-6 and the base count, and what would that base be?

@Johan Yes, The "prediction equation" is the $\hat{y}$ equation, or equation #2.

@Johan on your other comment about part (d), it might be useful to think of it this way:  The max math score is 75, and the min is 33. If you want to know the change in counts over the range, use $e^{\beta_3 (\max(x_3)-\min(x_3))} = 19.04$.  For example, in the Academic group, this takes the expected counts from 0.15 to 3.0.  So I see a change of 19x in counts over the range of math scores.

Thank you for your patience, or should I say sorry for the drag, @RCarnell. Sure, I can verify that the IRRs 19.03731*.1575147=~3. As a final comment though, can you please confirm or reject whether we can determine the (for a lack of a better word) 'theoretical' log-count scale based on the observed range of counts? E.g. we know num_awards ranges 0-6, but is it easy, perhaps meaningful, to describe the possible range or bounds of the estimates expressed as log-counts aka semielasticities of y? Even a yes/no would be helpful.
